# Superagent .attach throws error code 500

Tags: android, react-native, superagent, http-status-code-500

I want to upload a picture from phone (android) to a server (Editing avatar of a profile).
To select the picture i am using react-native-image-picker.

This is my API-Call

```
request
  .post(apiurl)
  .set("auth", token)
  .attach('avatar', avatar)
  .end(async function (err,res) {
    if(res.status === 200) {
      console.log("Update views...");
    }
  });
```

As far as is read and understood the docs, i just need to pass the filepath to the .attach function.
So mine looks like this (android):

```
avatar = file:///storage/emulated/0/path/on/phone/new_avatar.jpg
```

I get the path from the react-native-image-picker and add the **file://** at the beginning.

But what am I missing?

In the server logs we can see that it returns 500. In our API-Test class, at least as far as we tested it, it only returns 500, when it couldn´t find the file, e.g. a wrong path was passed as an argument.

Cheers and thanks in advance!